# I am unable to install react navigation using expo (react-native-gesture-handler isn't installed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm following the steps in [React Navigation](http://reactnavigation.org) to install it on an expo project, however it isn't working.

I am executing `expo install react-navigation react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens` in Windows CMD but it isn't installing anything besides react-navigation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the latest expo version then you can expo init demoApp command
then you will asked to select template, select tabs template which will take care of all the dependencies for react-navigation, and give you a start-up app to work on

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally found out the problem, it was installing but one of the modules had a problem (react-native-gesture-handler), seems like the last version of it has a bug, downgrading it did the trick.

Comment: glad i could help